# jdbc program to find the square of a number using callable statement (stored procedure )

Tags: mysql, jdbc, syntax

```
import java .sql.*;
class Pro
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"root","password");
CallableStatement cst=conn.prepareCall("{call fileproc(?,?)}");
cst.setInt(1,10);
cst.registerOutParameter(2,Types.INTEGER);
cst.execute();
int i=cst.getInt(2);
System.out.println("the number is :" +i);
cst.close();
conn.close();
}
}
```

In MYSQL:

```
fileproc:
CREATE  PROCEDURE fileproc(IN x INT,OUT y INT)
BEGIN
y := x * x;
END;
/
```

i'm getting an error at line 3 before entering END in fileproc as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= x
* x' at line 3.
```

what is the correct syntax?
please help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql>create database <database-name>;
     ->use <database-name>;
      delimiter //
      Create Procedure fileproc(in x int, out y int)
      begin
      set y = x * X;
      end //
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call(10,@y);
mysql> Select @y;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mysql stored procedure, remember to use 'set' keyword.